# opening a url in InappBrowser with target as _blank not working on latest iphones

Tags: cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

In my case I am using Iphone 11 pro Max.
In our hybrid application we open a login page using InAppBrowser and get back login response in our application.
Earlier it was working fine with _blank but suddenly in latest Iphones it stoped working.. _self target opens login url in InappBrowser but do not return response to original app. So this data transfer is not happening properly.

Kindly give me some solution on this.

Comment: Hi, have you solved the issue? I'm facing same. Can you help me through it?

Comment: No we are still facing it. Got no solution